# I don't know how to print in this case number 5. I also tried return

Tags: python, list, indexing, console, numbers

I would like to extract the `5`:

```
my_list = [[123],[456],[789]]
print(my_list[1][1])
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IK\PycharmProjects\WithoutUSB\Udemy course 1\more than 1 dimension.py", line 4, in <module>
    f()
  File "C:\Users\IK\PycharmProjects\WithoutUSB\Udemy course 1\more than 1 dimension.py", line 3, in f
    return(my_list[1][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access a position in an integer, you need to convert is to string first:

```
my_list = [[123],[456],[789]]
print(str(my_list[1][0])[1])
```

output: `5`

Breakdown:

```
>>> my_list[1]
[456]
>>> my_list[1][0]
456
>>> str(my_list[1][0])
'456'
>>> str(my_list[1][0])
'5'
```

Comment: You could add an `int` to convert `5` back to an integer in the end.

Answer (score 1):

you also define like this

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(my_list[1][1])
```